# I cannot share other folders to homegroup

Tags: network-shares

[image: http://www.evernote.com/shard/s209/sh/c7deb446-ba78-47e6-9231-211411d34ae5/f57eff5ece14de9acd903b622658c2ee]

So only pictures, videos, and music is shared. I tried to share other folders. I right click choose share with homegroup. Still if I go to homegroup all I see is music, pictures, and videos.

If I right click and select properties and then click sharing I got this:

[image]

Clearly the folder is shared with homegroup. But nothing shows up besides music pictures and videos on the first picture.

update

The folders are actually shared but in network instead of homegroup. I wonder why?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason you see Videos, Music, etc under Homegroup is because those aren't shared folders, they are shared *libraries*.

You can create a new library called, for example, HG-Shared, and then share that to the Homegroup, then add individual folders to that library. then they should all show under homegroup to other users.